# How to copy/run the components of one Angular app to another

Tags: angular, typescript, command-line-interface

I have two projects both developed in Angular, my first project is "zbarcode" and second project is "loginpage". Both the project structures have been created using Angular-cli.

Zbarcode structure -
[Zbarcode Structure (app.module.ts)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESQy7.png)

Loginpage structure -
[Loginpage Structure (app.module.ts)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vo0i.png)

If you look at the codes of loginpage component and module files, i want to add the zbarcode scannner component and features here. I dont know whether i can do it through angular routing or should i copy the contents of zbarcode to loginpage. The output i want is to run the scanner (zbarcode) after login (loginpage)

Thanks in Advance

Comment: just add modules of one project to another and update components in app.modules and other corresponding modules and update package.json and angular.json and index.html in single project. Angular app is all about "modules". Delete node_modules and kill terminal and re-run the app.

Comment: thanks but the answer of @draeger is more elaborate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already answered your question in the question itself, just replace the 'or' with 'and'. Following will be the steps -

1. Ensure what packages are actually making the 'zbarcode' work. You can find that in the package.json file. Install those packages in the 'loginpage' project of yours.
2. Copy the working code(rather components) from 'zbarcode' to 'login page' and parallelly import the components in the app.module.ts or they won't work. You will be prompted for that error anyways when you will be serving the project.
3. Now You have to make two routes e.g '/login' for the login page and '/zbar' for the bar scanner page. And if the user is verified using login, you simply want to redirect to '/zbar'.

Comment: hey i have another question. where will in the loginpage directory i will have to copy the contents of zbar... , is it in the app directory?